# Prior art for Vacuum Testing of Power Supply

Tags: prior-art-request, validity, us6570389

In reference to the patent: [US6570389](https://www.google.com/patents/US6570389)

This patent claims a method of vacuum testing of power supplies, and it was filed in June 2001.

I am wondering whether this is a standard procedure in the industry. Is there any prior art available?